# Inheriting from DefaultTrackableEventHandler

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

In the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs` script (attached to every `ImageTarget`) it is stated that it implements the `ITrackableEventHandler` interface and when implementing your own custom event-handler behavior, you should consider deriving from this class, instead of making changes to it directly.

However, when I do so and include my own custom code in the `override` methods after `base.OnTrackingFound()` and `base.OnTrackingLost()`, the code is never executed...

In the beginning, both `virtual` and `override` `Start()` methods (in `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs` and my own custom class) execute, but the `OnTrackingFound()` and `OnTrackingLost()` are not reached. My own script is attached to the same ImageTarget.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

p.s. All the tutorials I see online disregard this advice and either copy & paste the same code for `OnTrackingFound` and `OnTrackingLost` (i.e. duplicate it) and then add their custom code, or add their custom code directly in the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs` script...

```
using UnityEngine;

public class WaitState : DefaultTrackableEventHandler
{
    public GameObject _InfoCanvas;

    protected override void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("WaitState.Start()");
    }

    protected override void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        base.OnTrackingFound();

        Debug.Log("WaitState.OnTrackingFound()");

        _InfoCanvas.SetActive(false);
    }

    protected override void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        base.OnTrackingLost();

        Debug.Log("WaitState.OnTrackingLost()");

        _InfoCanvas.SetActive(true);
    }
}



using Vuforia;
using UnityEngine;

/// A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.
/// Changes made to this file could be overwritten when upgrading the Vuforia version.
/// When implementing custom event handler behavior, consider inheriting from this class instead.
public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    #region PROTECTED_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_PreviousStatus;
    protected TrackableBehaviour.Status m_NewStatus;

    #endregion // PROTECTED_MEMBER_VARIABLES


    #region UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("DefaultTrackableEventHandler.Start()");

        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();

        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this); 
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.UnregisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    #endregion // UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS


    #region PUBLIC_METHODS

    /// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function
    /// called when the tracking state changes.
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        m_PreviousStatus = previousStatus;
        m_NewStatus = newStatus;

        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
            OnTrackingFound();
        }
        else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&
                 newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
        else
        {
            // For combo of previousStatus=UNKNOWN + newStatus=UNKNOWN|NOT_FOUND
            // Vuforia is starting, but tracking has not been lost or found yet
            // Call OnTrackingLost() to hide the augmentations
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS


    #region PROTECTED_METHODS

    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents   = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Enable rendering.
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders.
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas'.
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        Debug.Log("DefaultTrackableEventHandler.OnTrackingFound()");
    }

    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Disable rendering.
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable colliders.
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable canvas'.
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        Debug.Log("DefaultTrackableEventHandler.OnTrackingLost()");
    }

    #endregion // PROTECTED_METHODS
}
```

Comment: looking for same!! Did you get the solution?

Comment: @vanshika Nope. Neither here nor even on the Vuforia's forum...

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the script to your ImageTarget GameObject - e.g the GameObject that has the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` script on it.

Because you're extending the class you can replace the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` script with your own `WaitState` script.

If you were doing this programmatically it would be similar to:

```
// assuming you're loading your dataset at runtime - 
// see https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/how-to-create-and-load-targets-in-unity.html

foreach (TrackableBehaviour trackableBehaviour in trackableBehaviours) {

  if (dataset.Contains(trackableBehaviour.Trackable)) {
    GameObject go = trackableBehaviour.gameObject;
    go.AddComponent<WaitState>();
  }

}
```

Otherwise just drag the script into the inspector for your ImageTarget GameObject.

I discovered this by looking at the [Vuforia Core Samples](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/packs/vuforia-core-samples-99026) on the Unity Asset Store.